# Oracle Apex Facebook Login : Your session has expired?

Tags: facebook, oracle-apex

I'm running Apex 19.2 on Oracle 18c XE database.

I have an application and I'm trying to add Facebook Login feature.

- I created the web credentials
- I created a new Authentication Scheme using the web credentials
- I added a button to a page with Apex authentication flag pointing on the new authentication Scheme (**APEX_AUTHENTICATION=Facebook**) and redirecting to a private page
- When I run the page and click the button, I'm redirected correctly to facebook, I authorize the app to access my information
- But when facebook redirects me to my page, I got the message, your session has expired.
- Also the code I added for debugging purposes in Post Authenticate procedure is not executing.

Can anyone help please ?

Thanks,
Cheers,

## Web Credentials :

[image]

## Authentication Scheme :

[image]

## Button :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the app at Facebook to generate appid and endpoint urls.